# Getting trouble with integer comparison using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison

I've following code

```
<input type="text" id="max_marks" name="max_marks" value="100">            
<input type="text" id="marks" name="marks" value="75" >
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#marks,#max_marks').change(function(){
                    var mm=$('#max_marks').val();
                    var m=$('#marks').val();

                    if(parseInt(mm,10) > parseInt(m,10))
                    {
                     alert("Maximum marks greater than obtained marks");   
                    }                        
                }).change(); 
            });

        </script>
```

The alert is firing when maximums marks are less than obtained marks.Where I'm doing the mistake ?

Comment: What is the value of `mm` and `m`?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/6PAgy/ Can you give more example code and tell us what values are being given for `m` and `mm`

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jNQy4/.

Comment: In such cases, debug your code and make sure `mm` and `m` are what you think they are. The operations involved are simple (it's just comparison) it's not difficult to trace the problem from the input to the output. Set breakpoints, go through your code step by step.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pv7MU/ also works fine for me

Comment: suppose mm=75 m=100, alert should not fire but its firing in this case

Comment: Given the code you have posted that is impossible - as it works in all three fiddles people have posted. Try Felixs' method for narrowing down the problem. It does not lie with the `parseInt()` section.

Comment: I don't know if it could help or is a problem with the event, but try changing .change() to .keypress() or .keyup()
everything is correctly for me!

Comment: What web browser are you using ? Some browsers only cast "change" when you unselect the box or type 'enter' no ? Could it be that the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes we can't predict the flow of client side scripting languages like jQuery and Javascript.Any how try following one

```
 <input type="text" id="max_marks" name="max_marks" value="100"><span></span>
 <input type="text" id="marks" name="marks" value="50" ><span></span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                function isNumberInt10(n) {
                         return !isNaN(parseInt(n,10)) && isFinite(n);
                        }
                function isValidMarks(m,n){

              if(parseInt(m) <= parseInt(n))
                    {   
                             return true;
                    }
                }        
                $('#max_marks').change(function(){

                 var mm=$('#max_marks').val();
                    if (!isNumberInt10(mm)) {
                        $('#max_marks').next().text('Enter valid marks');
                        $('#max_marks').attr('value','');
                        $('#max_marks').focus();
                        }
                   else
                    {
                        $('#max_marks').next().text('');
                        $('#max_marks').attr('value','');
                        $('#max_marks').focus();
                    }   
                    }).change(1000); 

           $('#marks').change(function(){        

                    var mm=$('#max_marks').val();
                    var m=$('#marks').val();

                  if (!isNumberInt10(m)) {
                        $('#marks').next().text('Enter valid marks');
                        $('#marks').attr('value','');
                        $('#marks').focus();
                        }
                   else
                    {    
                        $('#marks').next().text('');
                    }
                   if(isValidMarks(mm,m))
                    {   
                        $('#marks').next().text('Enter Valid obtained marks');
                        $('#marks').attr('value','');
                        $('#marks').focus();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#marks').next().text('');
                    }
                   }).change(1000);
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: lengthy code but working fine for my scenario,thanks

Comment: Nice job copying the important part of my solution, Mahesh D.

Answer (score 0):

The code as you've written it is vulnerable to incorrect numeric strings. I would suggest revising it like this:

```
function isNumberInt10(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseInt(n,10)) && isFinite(n);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#marks,#max_marks').change(function(){
        var mm, m;

        mm=$('#max_marks').val();
        if (!isNumberInt10(mm)) {
           alert("Max marks needs to be a number");
           return;
        }
        m=$('#marks').val();
        if (!isNumberInt10(m)) {
           alert("Marks needs to be a number");
           return;
        }

        if(parseInt(mm,10) > parseInt(m,10)) {
            alert("Maximum marks greater than obtained marks");   
        }                        
    }).change(); 
});
```